Extract Value from Array in Power Automate
I have an array as:
[
  {
    "Name": "Ca_somethingunkown"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Mv_somethingunkown"
  }
]

Am trying to get output in Power Automate as only "Mv_somethingunkown", while just searching as Mv as the array will be dynamic and after Mv the text will be changed everytime.
I tried Filter Array, Compose, Select, Startswith, Contains. But Either am getting again array as result or no output.
Expression I used in Filter Array is: @startwith(['Name'],'Mv')
Update
Post updating expression per Skin's Answer the Output is per below:
{
    "body":  [
        {
            "Name":"Mv_somethingunkown"
        }
    ]
}

I was trying to get the desired output as only "Mv_somethingunkown" as a string and no more arrays.

Is this PA cloud or desktop? Also, what expression have you tried as a filter for filter array?

This is PA cloud. While using filter array Used from as my array and filter query as Name->startswith->M. Result is  No Outputs

I can only suggest that you're not applying the expression(s) correctly ...

This is the Filter Array step ...

... the expression on the left is ...
item()['Name']

... so the entire expression in advanced terms is ...
startsWith(item()['Name'],'Mv')

Then to extract just the value, use an expression like this in a Compose operation ...
first(body('Filter Array'))['Name']

... or ...
body('Filter Array')[0]['Name']


Yes, I was using bad expression. Was looking for output as a string only and not array again. I updated question accordingly

Answer updated …!
